# How to render Box2D angles

Tags: box2d

My project is using Box2D as a pysics engine, and SDL to render.

Im trying to render a moving object that is able to rotate but it looks like im doing something wrong.

To fix my render problems I need to understand how I should draw it.

Lets say I have a car in Box2D with position 10,10 and an angle of 60 in degrees. The object has an fixture of 4 width, and 10 height. How should I render it?

**Option 1**
[image]
**Option 2**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some rendering code from a project I worked on using SDL/Box2D:

```
void Something::Render() 
{
    SDL_Rect stretchRect;
    stretchRect.x = (m_body->GetPosition().x * Constants::METRESTOPIXELS)  - (m_dimensions.x / 2);
    stretchRect.y = (-m_body->GetPosition().y * Constants::METRESTOPIXELS)  - (m_dimensions.y / 2);
    stretchRect.w = m_dimensions.x;
    stretchRect.h = m_dimensions.y;
    float angle = m_body->GetAngle() * Constants::TODEGREES;
    SDL_RenderCopyEx ( m_renderer, m_texture, NULL, &stretchRect, angle, NULL, SDL_RendererFlip::SDL_FLIP_NONE );
}
```

`METRESTOPIXLES` is the scaling for Box2d to pixels. `TODEGREES` is for converting radians to degrees. `m_body` is the Box2D body, and `m_dimensions`is whatever size the image should be. `m_renderer` is the `SDL_Renderer`, we passed a reference to it to the object in the object's constructor.